# json parse rails for showing result in select dropdown in edit form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following loop

```
<% @sub_categories.dropdown_heads.each do |label| %>
    <label for="login"><%= label.head_name %></label>
    <%= select_tag "post[dynam][#{label.head_name}]", options_for_select(generate_option(label)) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my helper function used for generating dropdown

```
def generate_option opt
    opt.dropdown_lists.inject([]) do |memo, cat|
      memo << [cat.list_name, cat.list_name]
    end
  end
```

The above piece of code will generate the following result(check the screen shot).

[image]

In my database table I have the column called content which holds similar datas

```
{"Style":"convertible","Year":"2010","Color":"green"}
```

Since the above code is from edit form, I need to show the selected values in select dropdown How can i parse the json data and show the chosen value any suggestion please.

**Edit 1**

I changed the line to

```
<%= select_tag "post[dynam][#{label.head_name}]", options_for_select(generate_option(label)), selected: get_value_for(label.head_name, @post) %>
```

It is not showing error but it is not filtering just displaying normally

My helper

```
def get_value_for(head_name, post)
    content_hash = JSON.parse post.content
    content_hash[head_name]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have another helper to get the value for the label.

```
<% @sub_categories.dropdown_heads.each do |label| %>
    <label for="login"><%= label.head_name %></label>
    <%= select_tag "post[dynam][#{label.head_name}]", options_for_select(generate_option(label), get_value_for(label.head_name, @post)) %>
<% end %>


def get_value_for(head_name, post)
  content_hash = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(post.content)
  content_hash[head_name]
end
```

I am assuming that you are setting @post in your controller and Post model is the one you are editing and it has the field content

Also this code is not tested. It should anyways give you the idea

Comment: Getting error as `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` in `select_tag` line

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not filtering just displaying normally"

Comment: It is not showing the selected value instead it is showing the default values